# Using a form option value as a PHP variable to execute prepared SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

I just started using PHP last week and I've been searching around for a solution for this quite extensively but I can't wrap my brain around the answers I've come across.

I essentially have a form that looks like this in index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="actionTest.php">
    <select name="courseID">
        <option value = "111">Course 1</option>
        <option value = "222"> Course 2 </option>
        <option value ="333"> Course 3 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then a prepared statement in my actionTest.php file

```
//variable for selected option value?
//$courseSelect = [???]

//query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ?";

//prepare the query
$q = $con->prepare($sql);

//execute the statement
$q->execute();

//setting fetch mode for statement
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//display fetched data
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    echo $r['name'] . "\n";
    echo $r['course_id'] . "\n";
    echo $r['description'] . "\n";
    echo "</br>";
}
```

I've written a simple PHP script that will echo what value has been selected when you submit the form, so I know I can retrieve the value I need.  I guess I'm generally confused about how to store the option value in a variable to pass to the query.  Any help or references to help are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$q->bindParam(1, $_POST['courseID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading from the manual (https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) you can bind your param in this way:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ?";
$q->bindParam(1, $myValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// insert one row
$myValue = $_POST['courseID'];
$q->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it would be as obvious as storing the data from the POST method as the value.

Comment: You're welcome, anyway @showdev response is very exaustive. If you think he gave you the correct answer please accept it as the useful one.

Comment: I utilized your simplified statement to retrieve the value and was successful :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for PDO [`bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

First, get your posted value. This code sets the variable to false if no value is posted:

```
$course_id= isset($_POST['courseID']) ? $_POST['courseID'] : false;
```

Then prepare your query:

```
// query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ?";

// prepare query
$q = $con->prepare($sql);

// bind the parameter to the query
$q->bindParam(1,$course_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

//execute the statement
$q->execute();

//display fetched data
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $r['name'] . "\n";
    echo $r['course_id'] . "\n";
    echo $r['description'] . "\n";
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Alternatively, in your context you can skip the bind and just execute with your parameter:

```
$q->execute(array($course_id));
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'll read more into bindParam() so I know how to use it in the future.  Seems kind of obvious now that you've pointed it out!

Comment: There are a number of powerful ways to use prepared statements. Definitely worth reading and checking out some of the examples.

Comment: I simplified the $course_id statement to just say $_POST['courseID'] - would this still be valid and free from injection?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I suggest that you validate the input before using it, but it's probably not a big deal in this context.